# MS SQL 2019 on RPi4 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install SQL Server 2019 on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 18.04.  I am trying to follow the installation guide from Microsoft:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017

However, when I get to step #2 to add the repo I get the following error:

> N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'

Has anyone else run into this?  Is there a way to resolve this or a workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: SQL Server runs on X86 or X86_64 architecture machines. Your Raspberry Pi is an ARM acrhitecture machine. Do you see the problem there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package doesn't support ARM64 architecture, so it has to be recompiled for that target. Also note you are trying to install an Ubuntu package, which evidently is not compiled for arm64 architecture.

You will need to find another SQL server package, is there a special reason why you want MS SQL?

Comment: I am just trying to get it to work on the Pi as a proof of concept.  It looks like Microsoft hasn't expanded this to work on ARM yet.  bummer

Comment: @silverbullettruck2001, I know this is an old question, but have you tried SQL Edge?, https://www.williamleme.com/posts/2021/001-sqlserver-on-raspberry-pi/